# Django 1.7 ContentType vs apps

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django 1.7 and i want to know the difference between using

```
ContentType.objects.get(app_label="app_name", model="model_name")
```

versus

```
apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

Do they both grab the same information from the model? what are the benefits of using apps.get_model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContentType.objects.get(app_label="app_name", model="model_name")
```

is only return instance of the [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) model class. But the

```
apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

return [model class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) of the `'app_name', 'model_name'`

more details in the code:

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

In [2]: from django.apps import apps

In [3]: ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myapp", model="bar")

In [4]: Bar = apps.get_model("myapp.bar")

In [5]: ct == Bar
Out[5]: False

In [6]: ct.model_class() == Bar
Out[6]: True

In [7]: Bar.objects.count()
Out[7]: 3

In [8]: ct.objects.count()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c27dfd7c7cf5> in <module>()
----> 1 ct.objects.count()

/home/user/.virtualenvs/so/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in __get__(self, instance, cls)
    184     def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
    185         if instance is not None:
--> 186             raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)
    187 
    188         if cls._meta.abstract:

AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via ContentType instances
```